# Random Number Generators are deterministic in a way? what is a way to use them so they cant be predicted?

Tags: seeding, random-seed

What i mean is that Random number generators are called Pseudo Random Generators as they give you values based of the seed. If you in your code dont set the seed, it gives you a sequence of random numbers based of some preexisting seed. What are good ways to make it unpredictable or non-deterministic?

For instance, for shuffling cards, maybe at a casino, you are playing a slot card game at 5:01 pm and so you can seed this with the linux time and hence, it keeps changing with time.

This is like an open discussion, am just curious about good ways to seed/ safe ways to seed

Comment: You want a [cryptographically-secure random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449594/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a truly random number to seed an RNG, try here: https://www.random.org/