# Generating random numbers, doesn't return some numbers

Tags: java, random

Just trying to generate 8 random numbers, but I'm only getting 3 numbers returned.

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class One{
  public static void main(String[] args){

      Random rand = new Random();
      int[] deciJunc = new  int[8];

      for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
          deciJunc[i] = 1+rand.nextInt(8);
          System.out.println(deciJunc[i]);
      }

  }
}
```

Output:

```
3
5
7
3
3
5
7
3
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
5
7
7
7
3
```

Now, I've ran this program like 10 times and it's only giving me these 3 numbers (3,5,7) and I don't understand what's wrong.
If I change:

```
deciJunc[i] = 1+rand.nextInt(8);
```

to

```
deciJunc[i] = 4+rand.nextInt(8);
```

It works fine, I get an output of a good mix like:

```
8
9
10
4
4
9
9
6
```

What's wrong with the first one where it only returns the 3 different numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with getting 3 different numbers in 8 possibiilites? That still fits the criterion of random

Comment: I get reasonable results when I run it.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem either: http://ideone.com/kzcWmG

Comment: You can try `SecureRandom`.

Comment: That is very, very odd. Could you try a larger sample size?

Comment: Could you also detail you exact system and Java version?

Comment: Can't help it: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @Bathsheba Just tried it with a range of 100 numbers and it works fine.
The original one I had a problem with works now, I don't know what fixed it.

Comment: It was a random effect, then.

Comment: Fun-fact of the day: probability of this happening is 8e-35. Congrats, you won the lottery 5 times in a row :D. (In case you actually ran it 10 times)

Comment: My guess is that the seed was retuning a very low positive value when you experienced the issue. I don't know enough about the Java random generators to comment further. These days though, a mersenne twister is a good all purpose generator.

Comment: @Bathsheba What do you mean by seed? (Sorry)

Comment: It's normally one before the first value of the random sequence. Normally it's correlated with the system clock time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for me Dear!

Please observe my results while running your code for multiple times:

> Result 1: 6, 5, 8, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2
>
> Result 2: 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 6, 8, 5

Still, if you are not satisfied with behavior of [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. You may wish to have a look at [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) from java Security package where Random Numbers are generated using Algorithms.

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class SecureRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            java.security.SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[128];
            secureRandomGenerator.nextBytes(randomBytes);
            int seedByteCount = 5;
            byte[] seed = secureRandomGenerator.generateSeed(seedByteCount);

            java.security.SecureRandom secureRandom1 = java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            secureRandom1.setSeed(seed);
            java.security.SecureRandom secureRandom2 = java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            secureRandom2.setSeed(seed);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new Exception("CustomAlgorithmNotFoundException" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

[Here you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449594/how-does-a-cryptographically-secure-random-number-generator-work) can find awesome explaintion about hoe SecureRandom works. Let me know if you need more help with the same.